# NextJs route.push() in custom page

Tags: next.js, router

I'm new in next js, I'm still practicing now, but I have suffered some problem, hope can find someone to help me find out the problem.

Here is my route.push():

```
onClick={(e) => {
              const query = { oid: data.oid, customer: data.cid };

              const url = { pathname: '/orders/detail/', query };

              const urlAs = { pathname: '/orders/detail/', query };

              router.push(url, urlAs);
            }}
```

and I hope my URL looks like `http://localhost:3000/orders/detail?id=1&customer=1`

and here is what my page folders look like
[pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwL3D.png)

why it didn't render the `[oid].js' inside the folders??

and it runs an error message here [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmaR1.png)

Thanks for all your helping and advice, It will mean a lot to me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that pages folder structure, your url should look like `http://localhost:3000/orders/detail/someID/someOID`.

The urlAs feature is no longer used for routing. (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush)

I would just do

```
onClick={(e) => {
  router.push(`/orders/detail/${data.cid}/${data.oid}`);
}
```

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
onClick={(e) => {
  router.push({
              pathname: '/orders/detail/[id]/[oid]',
              query: { id: data.cid, oid: data.oid },
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question!!! Here is one more question I have, if I want to make the URL looks another way, not just like `/order/detail/cid/oid`, what should I do for those folders settings? Or what will you do in your way, if just want to customize it randomly?~~~

Comment: What do you mean by customizing randomly? Can you give an example?

Comment: To achieve path `http://localhost:3000/orders/detail?id=1&customer=1` the file/folder should be just `/orders/details.js`. The query params can then be accessed through router at least (and through context in getServerSideProps I think)

Comment: See https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes for how to access those params

Comment: This is what I am looking for !!!! Sorry, I didn't explain my problem very well, but you still help me fixed the problem!!! I'll keep practicing, and try to use your way to code!! Thanks a lot!! Have a nice day~

Comment: Thank you, awesome that it was helpful. Please accept the answer if your problem was solved.